# PHP How to add/insert table(s) in a table in Firebase

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to add/insert table(s) in a table in Firebase?

I have a table called "users" in my firebase database and it looks like this :

[image]

As you can see the key is the ID and the value is the name of the user.
This is a simple structure, but i want is to have multiple tables in my main table "users", like this :

[image]

I am coding in PHP and this is the function i am using to insert data :

```
public function insert(array $data) {

    if (empty($data) || !isset($data)) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $this->database->getReference()->getChild($this->table)->getChild($key)->set($value);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do Something like that

```
$postData = [
    'UserWatchList' => [
       ['Player' => 'Player1'],
       ['Player' => 'Player2']
    ]
];

// Create a key for a new user in users table
// Note: if you have user key then you don't need to create a key
$newUserKey = $db->getReference('users')->push()->getKey();    

$updates = [
    'users/'.$newPostKey => $postData,
];    

$db->getReference() // this is the root reference
   ->update($updates);
```

Reference: https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/realtime-database.html#update-specific-fields